# How to call a warpscript macro from another local file

Tags: warp10, warpscript

**strong text**I just begin to learn WarpScript. My task is to refactor a bigger code base. First i want to split large files into smaller junks (by concern/ function). But how to do this?
I created a minimal example that is executed locally on docker based Warp10:

file mine.mc2 (an example of file/ macro that i want to call from other file):

```
<%
    'greeting' STORE
    $greeting
%> 'hello' STORE

'hello world' @hello
```

this is working and output is

```
["hello world"]
```

as expected

2nd file that should use the macro/ code from mine.mc2:

```
"hello world" @hello
```

but this isn't working:
`Exception at '"hello world" =>@hello<=' in section [TOP] (Unknown macro 'hello')`

i also tried `@mine`, `@/mine` here the error changes a bit to `('mine' is not a macro.)`.

So how to get this working?

And more general how to correctly include other files and reference the macros within? I want to have self contained code split into multiple files.

**Edit or rephrase** taking into account that everything is executed remotely:

Is there a way to implement code (in general multiple files with macros referencing mutually) quickly deploy it (all of it) and run it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is specific to VSCode WarpScript plugin:

add

```
// @include macro: mine
```

at the beginning of your code. this includes the reference macro - only if run within VSCode. For developing it might be enough.